How do I update timestamp values in a BigQuery table?
I need to update some date values that were stored incorrectly. I have two tables of data that I am combining. Basically, table1 and table2 contain consecutive months of the same data. Table1 has the year as "2016" and table2 represented as "0016". This makes it difficult to ORDER BY date when the two are combined into one table. The full values in the new (extracted) date column looks like "0016-05-02" and "2016-04-12" for example. the date_time column in both original tables are stored as the timestamp datatype.
How do I change the "0016" year value to "2016" down the column in the new table?
SELECT
  id,
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM date_time) AS date,
  EXTRACT(TIME FROM date_time) AS time,
  WeightKg,
  WeightPounds,
  Fat,
  BMI,
  IsManualReport,
  LogId
FROM `projectname.fitness_data.weight_log_table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Id,
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM date_time) AS date,
  EXTRACT(TIME FROM date_time) AS time,
  WeightKg,
  WeightPounds,
  Fat,
  BMI,
  IsManualReport,
  LogId
FROM `projectname.fitness_data.weight_log_table2`
ORDER BY id, date, time

Also, I'm using the new standard SQL for BigQuery, not the legacy dialect.
I assume I need to use the UPDATE function, but I'm not sure where to start.
The desired result would be all the values in the date column represented as year 2016 (for example, 2016-04-18).

Maybe something like UPDATE SET  WHERE  < "1000-01-01"
The newDate would be constructed from the oldDate ... I'd extract year, month and day and create the newDate from the same month and day and add 2000 to the year.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not a free code writing service, you need to show the SQL you’ve managed to write so far and ask a question about the specific issue you are stuck on

The first thing I'd check is the schema as the value "0016" is possibly not a valid timestamp value. I'd posit that the field is a string. However, for the solution below I am treating it as a timestamp.
Fix the value dynamically at runtime
SELECT
  id,
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM date_time) AS date,
  EXTRACT(TIME FROM date_time) AS time,
  WeightKg,
  WeightPounds,
  Fat,
  BMI,
  IsManualReport,
  LogId
FROM `projectname.fitness_data.weight_log_table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT
  Id,
  --fix the date field
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM CAST(REPLACE(CAST(date_time AS STRING),"0016-","2016-") AS TIMESTAMP)) AS date,
  EXTRACT(TIME FROM date_time) AS time,
  WeightKg,
  WeightPounds,
  Fat,
  BMI,
  IsManualReport,
  LogId
FROM `projectname.fitness_data.weight_log_table2`
ORDER BY id, date, time

What I am doing here is:

convert the date_time value to a string so we can search and replace the 0016 value
replace "0016" with "2016". I am including the "-" to ensure it doesn't match anything else by accident, as the 4-digit year + "-" are a safe bet.
turn the string date back into a timestamp (if it was a timestamp to begin with)
extract the date element

Fix the value at source:
UPDATE `projectname.fitness_data.weight_log_table2`
SET date_time = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(date_time AS STRING),"0016-","2016-") AS TIMESTAMP)
WHERE CAST(date_time AS STRING) LIKE '0016-%"

